# How to implement this loss in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to implement this loss like this: 
[image: Loss]

This is code:

```py
def loss(output, target, from_logits=False):


        L1 = - tf.reduce_sum(target * tf.log(output), reduction_indices=len(output.get_shape()) - 1)
        L2 = tf.reduce_sumr(tf.square(tf.subtract(tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(j,output),  reduction_indices=len(output.get_shape()) - 1), y))))
        L3 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(output,tf.square(tf.subtract(j,tf.reduce_prod(tf.multiply(k,p<sub>i,k</sub>)))))))
        loss = L1 + L2 + L3
        return loss
```

- How about formula that I implement? Is that right?

Please hep me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Supposing you have `y_true` with shape `(samples, 11)`, one hot encoded.
- Supposing that you are using a `softmax` (classes sum = 1) activation in the last layer

A loss in Keras has the form `def func(y_true, y_pred):`

```py
import keras.backend as K
from keras.losses import categorical_crossentropy

def loss(y_true, y_pred):

    #p
    p = y_pred                                        #(samples,11)

    #j or k
    j = K.cast_to_floatx(K.arange(10,21))             #(11,)
    j = K.reshape(j, (1,-1))                    #(1,11)

    #y_true as class number
    y = K.sum(y_true * j, axis=-1, keepdims=True)    #(samples, 1)

    #first term:
    L1 = categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)     #(samples,)

    #second term with y outstide sum in j
    kpk = j * p                                   #(samples, 11)
    kpkSum = K.sum(kpk, axis=-1, keepdims=True)   #(samples, 1)
    L2 = kpkSum - y                               #(samples, 1)
    L2 = K.square(L2) / 2.                        #(samples, 1)

    #third term:
    L3 = K.square(j - kpkSum)                      #(samples,11)
    L3 = p * L3                                    #(samples,11)
    L3 = K.sum(L3, axis=-1)                        #(samples,)

    return L1 + L2 + L3 #the mean in N is automatic by Keras
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I think L3 = K.sum(kpk, axis=-1, keepdims=True) should be L3 = K.sum(kpk, axis=-1). Because (j-L3)^2 means, if L3 = 15 then (10-15)^2, (11-15)^2,..., (19-15)^2,(20-15)^2. Is it right?

Comment: We need `keepdims` to make sure the difference is occurring at the correct axis (see the shapes commented in every line, its `(samples,1)`, not `(samples,11)`)

Comment: Thank you. Probl 1. I think j = K.reshape(classes, (1,-1)) should be j = K.reshape(j, (1,-1)). Is this right? Probl 2. y = K.sum(y_true * j, axis=-1, keepdims=True)  #(samples, 1)  kpk = j * p  #(samples, 11) L2 = kpk - y  #(samples, 11) L2 = K.sum(L2, axis=-1)  #(samples,) They if y = 15, (10*0.01+11*0.02+...+ 15*0.9+...+19*0.02+20*0.01 -15) -15. I this right? Probl 3. I don't know how you could print #(sample,1) to check shape and check thier value?

Comment: Fixed problem 1, you can print the shapes with `print(K.int_shape(var))` -- For problem 2 it really depends whether y is inside the sum or outside, and the formula is not clear about that. I assumed it inside the sum

Comment: Many thanks for you. For L2: y is insde the sum of i from 1 to n and out side the sum of j from 1 to K. It means (total of (j * p<sub>i,j</sub>)) minus y<sub>i</sub> (real number - real number). For L3: z = total of (k * p<sub>i,k</sub>) and total with i from 1 to N (total with j from 1 to K (p<sub>i,j</sub> times the square of (j-z))).

Comment: I fixed L2 (y outside the j-sum). But I didn't understand 3. I believe the parentheses must be inside the j-sum, right?

Comment: But I suspect in L2 the `y` should also be inside the j-sum, by comparing the values, it's very likely that y must be subtracted from all things multiplied by j.

Comment: Thank you. For L2: y is outsize the j-sum. It's Ok. For L3: parentheses must be inside the j-sum. For example: For  i = 1, the every j from 1 to K, j always minus the same value of kpkSum. kpkSum is real number.